# How to do match_parent in iOS

Tags: android, ios

I am used to having an Android background where I do:

```
android_layout_width="match_parent" or android_layout_height="match_parent"
```

How is this behavior done on iOS, using xib?

Answer (score 10):

1) Set frame of child view matching parent's view bounds.
2) Enable autoresizing mask like in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This is the easiest one!

Answer (score 2):

You have to create two constraints from the child to it's parent view:

- equal width
- equal height

[image: UIB define constraint]

It's also possible to define a margin (select the created constraint within the size inspector)
[image]

Comment: This way is new with AutoLayout. better than AutoResizing